# making a chessboard with arrays of JPanel

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I 'm doing a chessboard , my idea is to make an array of JPanels , each box is a JPanel with color, the problem I have , when I make such assignment
" chessboard [ rows ] [columns ] = b" and compile gives me an exception .

Why the assignment gives me an error ?

How I can fix it?

Is the layout grid , should go in the JFrame or JPanel ?

thanks.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

First Class

```
public class ChessBoard extends JPanel {
    private JPanel[][] chessBoardSquares = new JPanel[8][8];

    private final JPanel tile;


    public ChessBoard () {
        tile = new JPanel();
         tile.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

        for (int rows = 0; rows < 8; rows++) {
            for (int columns = 0;columns< 8;columns++) {
               JPanel b = new JPanel();

                 chessBoardSquares  = new JPanel[rows][columns];

                if ((rows+columns +1)%2 == 0){
                    b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
               chessBoardSquares[rows][columns] = b;
                }

               tile.add(   chessBoardSquares [rows][columns]);
            }


        }

    }

}
```

main

```
public class example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {



JFrame window = new JFrame();

 ChessBoard chessBoard = new  ChessBoard();


    window.add( chessBoard  );
    window.setVisible(true);



    }

}
```

Comment: how often do you initialize `chessBoardSquares`? I think it is a bit too much if you do it inside the inner for-loop.
`

Comment: the teacher told me I should save memory within loops.  I've seen the error and I have solved, thank you very much .

Answer (score 2):

You're not filling your array properly.

This

```
    for (int rows = 0; rows < 8; rows++) {
        for (int columns = 0;columns< 8;columns++) {
           JPanel b = new JPanel();

             // ***** this creates a completely new array *******
             chessBoardSquares  = new JPanel[rows][columns];
```

should be

```
    for (int rows = 0; rows < 8; rows++) {
        for (int columns = 0;columns< 8;columns++) {
           JPanel b = new JPanel();

             // this assigns a JPanel to an array item
             chessBoardSquares[rows][columns] = new JPanel();
```

Also as an aside, I don't see where you're adding the tile JPanel to your GUI, and you'll want to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be better like this :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ChessBoard extends JPanel {

    private final JPanel[][] tiles = new JPanel[8][8];

    public ChessBoard() {
        Dimension dims = new Dimension(64, 64);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                JPanel b = new JPanel();
                b.setPreferredSize(dims);
                b.setMinimumSize(dims);
                if ((i + j + 1) % 2 == 0) {
                    b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                } else {
                    b.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                add(b);
                tiles[i][j] = b;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Chess");
        ChessBoard chessBoard = new ChessBoard();
        f.add(chessBoard);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```